# Returning two strings after small delay?

Tags: python

This is my code. I want to return str1 and after 20-30 seconds return str2.
I know i cant tipe two times return str1 and below it str2.
how can i set timer to it so it returns, i tried like this but dont have ideas any more.

```
import os
import sys
import time
from weather import *

greeting=(["Change", "change", "CHANGE"]) question_1=(["stop",
"STOP"])

str1 = """Hey [First Name]! 

Are your ready for a free overview of my favorite ways to find new
income opportunities?

This is going to CHANGE the way you look at your options!

It’s kinda weird, but Facebook requires that I confirm you really want
it…so please reply and type  CHANGE"""

str2 = """ Hey [First Name]! Thanks for subscribing! As promised here
is your requested link  https://thebusinessofnursing.com/earn-more-now


P.S. If you ever want to unsubscribe, just type “stop”."""

def classify(msg):
    msg=msg.strip()
    if(msg in greeting):
        return str1

def classify2(msg):
    time.sleep(5)
    return str2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while(1):
        msg=raw_input("Write Something: ")
        print(classify(msg), classify2(msg))
```

Comment: Put your code in a code block please.  Always.

Comment: use button `{}` to format code

Comment: Why do you need it to return twice? What happens after return?

Comment: It sends a message. If i use print it just prints it in console and it doesnt send a message :/ its for messenger bot

Comment: Maybe consider amend this question with the actual code in question that uses whatever messenger bot API that you may be using.

Comment: Wow you are one of those guys that send me 100 Emails every day how I can get free income? No, I won't help you.

Comment: Nope, this is actualy for one of my fiverr clients, i was doing simple bots but i never really had to use timer so.. crying...

Answer (score 4):

You can yield it

```
def gen():
    yield str1
    time.sleep(sec)
    yield str2
```

Or

```
def gen(str_list, delay):
    yield str_list[0]
    for str in str_list[1:]:
        time.sleep(delay)
        yield str
```

One of the possible usages could be

```
for str in gen(str_list, 20):
      do_some_stuff()
```

Comment: How would i implement it ? Im tring for whole day and im getting more confused :S

Comment: Implement what ?

Comment: the code you wrote, i never used yield. Im really confused now

Comment: functions that uses yield are called generators, here is a great explanation  https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/5672176.
If you don't care about how generator works and you prefer to call it magic think of it as a return statement that return a value on each iteration (so each time we call the next(my_gen))

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to delay a print

```
import time

print("first thing")
time.sleep(20)
print("second thing")
```

Comment: printing wont work because it prints it in terminal and it doesnt send a message it needs to return